# Can I destructure a property into the same property of an object literal?

Tags: javascript

This is at the Node.js REPL:

```
> action = {type: 'build', index: 42 }
{ type: 'build', index: 42 }
> { name: 99, {index : action} }
{ index: { type: 'build', index: 42 } }
```

Where did `name: 99` go?

I was hoping for:  `{ name: 99, index: 42 }`.  Obviously my attempt is wrong.

One way, without destructuring would be:

```
{ name: 99, index: action.index }
```

But, how do I get what I was hoping for `{ name: 99, index: 42 }` using some kind of destructing...or more specifically, with economical syntax, and without having to mention `index` twice?

Comment: how do you execute that? `{ name: 99, {index : action} }` is invalid syntax since there is key missing for `{index: action}` value

Comment: There is no destructuring here?

Comment: @skyboyer no, that's a block statement, a label and a comma operator :)

Comment: @skyboyer it's actually valid syntax. But it is a [code block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) `name: 99` followed by a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and the object literal `{index : action}`.

Comment: And to actually answer your question: nope. That's not yet possible.

Comment: Sorry if I have my terminology wrong regarding "destructuring".  If there's a more appropriate word for what I'm trying to do, please enlighten me.  Thanks, everyone, for breaking it down.  And wow, this was really mystifying that I stumbled upon that label + comma + literal oddity.  Makes sense now.

Comment: @JonasWilms, if you want to write a "nope, that's not yet possible" answer, I'd mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The destructuring syntax evaluates to *the value being destructured*, so `({ a } = b)` evaluates to `b`. Thus, there is no way to use destructuring inside object literals. Also there is yet no other way to do that.

A [language proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements#object-initializers) that would allow the syntax to be

```
 { action.index }
```

seems to be far away from being standardized.

---

As a sidenote: Your attempt did not work, cause it actually builds up only one object. The outer `{}` are interpreted as a block statement, the `name:` as a label, the following `,` as a comma operator, thus the following `{}` are in expression context and are interpreted as an object literal:

```
{ // block
  name: // label
  (99, {index : action}) // comma operator
}
```